# Call method every time a second has passed

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a table view with a count down timer in each cell. I'd like them to count down one second at the exact same moment.

My first attempt was to use an NSTimer for each table view cell:

```
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimerLabel"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But as soon as I scroll down in my table view new cells appear with their timers being initialized at that very moment, thus out of sync with the timers in my other cells.

**What can I do to keep my labels getting updated all at the exact same time?**

One thing I'm thinking of is initializing a single NSTimer in my table view controller, which fires an update method on all of my visible cells.

However, I'm hoping for something like a system wide notification of some sort that fires every time a second passes on my devices internal clock. Thus making sure my timers are not only in sync with each other, but also with the system time displayed in the status bar.

Comment: Create a single timer when the view is loaded, which calls a function in which every label gets updated

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you provided your own answer.  Use your existing NSTimer to send a notification and have each table cell subscribe to that notification and respond accordingly. But you know that already ... what am I missing?

Comment: There is no timer that will run your code exactly at the same time the system clock increments by a second. Your idea to use one timer for all of the cells is sound.